# Javascript selectedindex not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that should allow me to show div id='yestext' when 'Yes' is selected in the dropdown box. Yet this is not working. I don't know what isn't working, but something clearly isn't.

**JS**

```
    function text() {
        if (document.getElementById("text").selectedIndex == "0") {
          document.getElementById("yestext").style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
          document.getElementById("yestext").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <select id='text' onchange='text()'>
   <option value="0">Yes</option>
   <option value="1">No</option>
 </select>
 <div style='display:none;' id='yestext'>
   What text would you like displayed?
   <input type='text' class='text' name='type' value size='20'/>
 </div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle containing my code: http://jsfiddle.net/4w9fh/

Comment: Looks like [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/FvuLu/) works fine... The original-one just has a timing issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'timing'?

Comment: Below the library drop-down you can find another drop-down, with which you can choose a place for the script. In your fiddle you've selected "`Onload`", which is not working with globals at jsFiddle. In my fiddle I've chosen "`No wrap -in head`". There was also an answer here, in which you were adviced to remove the quotes around `0`, since `selectedIndex` returns a number.

Comment: okay, I get that, but how do you change that in raw code?

Comment: If you are expecting the extra div to be displayed onload then you need to call the text() function first.  Your code only updates on the onchange event

Comment: Just take care your script is in the `head` or in the `body`, but not between them. BenM mentioned something about `Object is not function error`, when the script was placed within `head`. I couldn't reproduce it, can you see any errors in your console?

Comment: If you can't post anything which helps to reproduce your problem, I'm afraid I've to vote to close this question because: "`This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced...`" @smitt04 Removing the `style` attribute from `#yestext` would also show the `div` at start.

Comment: The solutions work fine in JSFiddle, but as soon as I paste them into my code they don't work

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? If no errors, please post your full code exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The You had the JSFiddle set to run your code in `OnLoad` and it wrapped the `text()` function so it did not add it to global namespace. I fixed it by moving the js to the head and now it works.

I also called the `text()` function when the html finishes loading to take in account the browser remembering the last choice.

Here is the updated code.
http://jsfiddle.net/4w9fh/2/